# Need Binding agent ideas

Tags: food-science

I need help getting cooked grains (I.e. sorghum, barley, farro) to clump together but maintain a relatively dry texture. I’m cooking for my 18 month old and he likes grains but picks up a single grain at a time. I want them to clump together so he gets more per bite  (preferably without a sweetener or low sugar option). I would love to use eggs for the nutritional and caloric value but would need to cook most of the moisture out of it—and I can’t get away with a frittata-as he does not like scrambled eggs or things with wet/mushy texture. Eggs alone were a fail in binding.

Comment: The answer likely depends at what temperature you're going to be serving it at, but my first thought would be to add some rice flour and see if you can get it to stick like a risotto, but it might need to be cool or cold to get it to clump like you want